# Transferred to new hosting/server - Now having issues with using MySQL for form validation

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, validation

I'm having a lot of problems with the new hosting, but the more I look at it, it seems that they're all related to doing checks in my database when validating logins, registrations, and submissions. Here's an example of one.

I use jQuery to [validate forms](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation). One I use to determine if a username actually exists when a user is trying to log in (don't worry, I also check server side). On my development server, this works flawlessly. If you're not familiar with jQuery Validation, basically this returns a true or false back to the server in a form of some kind of JSON, but I'm not entirely knowledgeable on that part.

The code:

```
//Database Information vars (removed)

mysql_connect ($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)or die("Could not connect: ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($login_username); // In validation, I can grab inputs like this.

$query = "SELECT username FROM registerusers WHERE username='$username';";

$res = mysql_query($query);

if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
    $output = true;
} else {
    $output = false;    
}

echo json_encode($output);
```

The problem with this is that it always refers to the first clause and returns true, even if the username does not exist. For whatever reason, I think it's always returning 1 for `mysql_num_rows($res)`.

This EXACT code (except for new database vars which I've checked a hundred times to be accurate) works as intended on my development server still. I can only assume that it has something to do with the new server, and that's why I'm asking Stack Overflow, because I have no clue.

Comment: Have you checked the actual 'JSON' this returns? It might be that there's an error of some sort that screws up your return values which jQuery then always evaluates to true...

Comment: Can you try outputting $query to check if the query looks the way you intend it to?

Comment: Where do you give `$login_value` a value?

Comment: @Dan I've thought about that, but the problem with that is that this is a remote method for jQuery validation. It is looking for either a true or false return and does something based on the return. Is there another way to test this and find out that value?

Comment: Yes, use the Firefox or Chrome browser and check the network connections coming in. One of them will be the ajax response and have the value in it you're looking for.

Comment: @Repox You mean `$login_username`, right? That's just how you grab inputs in jQuery validation. This works fine on the development server, so I'm kind of assuming that's how its supposed to be done.

Comment: @MarkLyons Yeah, that's the one I meant. You probably have register_globals enabled on your development server  (which is a big no-no). Try typing `$_POST['login_username']` instead.

Comment: I'll give that a try. I think that will fix it for sure because I've been testing just putting in usernames instead of `$username` and that works fine. I'll let you know how that goes.

Comment: @Repox Works great! It was actually a `$_GET`, but it works. Using a GET request wouldn't post any security issues though, right? If you want to give an actual answer I'd select yours. Thanks to @Dan and @Joep as well.

Comment: @MarkLyons I posted my suggestions as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that register_globals is enabled.
This poses a high security problem which is why it is disabled and deprecated.

Changing `$login_username` to `$_GET['login_username']`solves the problem.

Using the $_GET and $_POST super global arrays is not a security problem, but you should always sanitize your input (like you do with mysql_real_escape_string()).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the MySQL connection to a variable, then calling the connection variable as the second parameter inside of the mysql_query? This has sometimes given me an issue on some servers, especially if they have certain debugging methods, errors, and warnings shut off by default:

```
//Database Information vars (removed)

$connect = mysql_connect ($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Could not connect: ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($login_username); // In validation, I can grab inputs like this.

$query = "SELECT `username` FROM `registerusers` WHERE `username` = '".$username."';";

$res = mysql_query($query, $connect);

if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
    $output = true;
} else {
    $output = false;    
}

echo json_encode($output);
```

I've also changed the $query to a concatenated string with the variable, as some servers I have worked on sometimes are finicky in terms of putting variables inside of a string without delimiting them with "..".

Comment: Thanks for looking at this Shaun. If you look in the comments, Repox showed me that it was because register_globals is set to on on the EWS dev server. I think this is the cause of all the other problems I've been having, like sessions not starting. I'll give your answer a try as well just to make sure I understand this right.